# C compile error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c, string, syntax

In C, I try to assign a string:

```
void addressItem_icon_download_callback(const char* res_name, 
                                        int success, 
                                        void *context, 
                                        char *last_modified){

    char *icon = ((AddressItem_Callback_ContextType)context)->Icon;
}
```

and get this error:

```
conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

What does the error mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `AddressItem_Callback_ContextType` is a struct with a field Icon (`char*`)

```
typedef struct
{
  char *Icon;
}AddressItem_Callback_ContextType;
```

try

```
char *icon = ((AddressItem_Callback_ContextType*)context)->Icon;
```

First you must cast your context into a pointer `AddressItem_Callback_ContextType*`
and then only you can access to the field using the "->"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure AddressItem_Callback_ContextType is apointer type? you can cast a pointer type (here context) to another pointer type only.

May be you need to cast context to (AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *).